# dsss makefile install error, missing std.ctype.d file (Windows)

Tags: makefile, d, dsss

I try to download [dsss](https://github.com/apriori/dsss) for d programming and try to make file by following the instruction from [link](https://github.com/apriori/dsss/blob/master/docs/INSTALL)

```
> ....it just show module ctype cannot read file 'stdc\ctype.d'
```

I looked up **/sss/config.f** folder and it imports a file called **ctype.d**
but there is not such file in **D** Language's Phobos library
anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DSSS](https://github.com/apriori/dsss) is an old tool, and I also believe it is a discontinued project. Try [DUB](http://code.dlang.org) instead  and see whether it suits your needs.

Comment: I found out that it only support D1 and that's why is has that error.
I'm currently using D2 already.